# How do I change the title in this wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress

The class site-title is an h1 and contains the link. When I type

```
   site-title a {
   color:red;
   }
```

It does not work, I cant fiqure out what overrides it.

http://18.188.151.223/

Comment: Do you need a period in front of the class name?  .site-title a { color:red; }

Comment: that is just a type here

Answer (score 0):

style.css add this code line number :1605 after

```
.site-title a {
    color:red;
}
```

another option

```
.site-title a {
    color:red !important;
}
```